# iPhone - How to restore frame size after entering foreground?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I changed `UINavigationBar`'s height by changing its frame.
But it's height restores to its original size if I send application to background and then open it again. How can I fix that?

Comment: where are you changing it's height? are you doing this in viewDidLoad of a ViewController?

Comment: yes, in ViewdidLoad and in ViewDidAppear also

Comment: should be doing this only once, remove it from viewDidAppear

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You could write the frame to a resource file like a plist or XML file. Then load the plist in the app delegate file in either the `-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application' or`-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`. I believe you could also use NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *frameSize = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

//Put frame size into defaults
[sharedDefaults setObject:navigationBar.frame forKey:@"frame"];
[sharedDefaults synchronize];
```

Then in the aforementioned App Delegate methods, you could do something like this:

```
self.viewController.navigationController.frame = [sharedDefaults objectForKey:@"frame"];
```

Hope this helps and if it did, remember to up vote.

-----------EDIT------------

If you look at this question [iOS selected tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608669/ios-selected-tab), it tells you how to determine which tab is selected. What they basically say is to first add `self.tabController.delegate = self` in the app delegate, and make sure that the app delegate and the view controller with the tab bars conform to the UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol. Then in your View Controller file with the tab bars, you can use this method defined in the protocol:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) { 
    //The 0 is the first tab, but you can replace that with any other tab's index

         //Here you say that when said tab is selected, the navigation controller's frame is the stored length.
         self.navigationController.frame = [sharedDefaults objectForKey:@"frame"]; 
    }
    else{
         self.navigationController.frame = CGRectMake(frame, for, other, tabs);
    }
}
```

Comment: My app has 4 tabs, UINavigationBar height should be changed only in one of these tabs. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with tab bars, so I'm afraid I can't help you right now, but I'll look into it. Sorry

Comment: You can also keep the tab index in `NSUserDefaults` as `NSNumber`, if you want to keep all tabs frames, again you can keep them in `NSUserDefaults` as an `NSMutableArray`object which contains `NSNumber` objects or use `NSMutableDictionary` etc.. Hope that will give you some inspiration.